# I need to scale a 2d square using java

Tags: java, opengl

I'm writing a program to transform, rotate and scale a 2d square. I have the transformation and rotation working but I need help with the scaling. I can't seem to find any help on the internet to help since I have to use a math equation and I can't find the equation needed. Just so you know I don't want to use gl.glScaled(). I need to use a math equation but I can't figure it out.

```
package lab2;


public class Square {

public double [][] vertices = new double[4][2]; 


public Square(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    vertices[0][0]=x1;
    vertices[0][1]=y1;
    vertices[1][0]=x2;
    vertices[1][1]=y2;
    vertices[2][0]=x3;
    vertices[2][1]=y3;
    vertices[3][0]=x4;
    vertices[3][1]=y4;
}

public double area()
{
    return (vertices[1][0]-vertices[0][0])*(vertices[1][0]-vertices[0][0])+(vertices[1][1]-vertices[0][1])*(vertices[1][1]-vertices[0][1]);
}

public void translate(double tx, double ty)
{
    for(int i=0;i<vertices.length;i++)
    {
        vertices[i][0]+=tx;
        vertices[i][1]+=ty;
    }
}
public void rotate(double theta)
{
    //double x =0;
    double x = (vertices[0][0]+vertices[2][0])/2;
    double y = (vertices[0][1]+vertices[2][1])/2;

    double oldX;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        oldX = vertices[i][0];
        vertices[i][0] = x + (vertices[i][0]-x)*Math.cos(theta*0.0174532925199)-(vertices[i][1]- y)*Math.sin(theta*0.0174532925199);
        vertices[i][1] = y + (oldX-x)*Math.sin(theta*0.0174532925199)+(vertices[i][1]-y)*Math.cos(theta*0.0174532925199);
    }
}

public void scale(double sx, double sy)
{

}
}
```

Then I also have this SquareControl.java so that I can control how I want it to work so for this program I'll be using key events

```
package lab2;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

import com.sun.opengl.util.Animator;
import com.sun.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class Square_Control implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {

Square square = new Square(100,100,200,100,200,200,100,200);
boolean rotating = false;
boolean scaling = false;
boolean enlarge = true;
double theta = 1;
double sx = 1.01, sy = 1.01;
GLProfile glp;
GLCapabilities caps;
GLCanvas canvas;

public Square_Control()
{
    glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        Frame frame = new Frame("AWT Window Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
                }
        });

        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.addKeyListener(this);
        canvas.requestFocus();
        Animator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas,60);
        animator.add(canvas);
        animator.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Square_Control sqc = new Square_Control();

}

public void update()
{
    if (rotating)
        square.rotate(theta);
    if (scaling)
    {
        square.scale(1, 1);

    }
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    update();
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
            gl.glVertex2d(square.vertices[0][0], square.vertices[0][1]);
            gl.glVertex2d(square.vertices[1][0], square.vertices[1][1]);
            gl.glVertex2d(square.vertices[2][0], square.vertices[2][1]);
            gl.glVertex2d(square.vertices[3][0], square.vertices[3][1]);
        gl.glEnd();



}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(0, 300, 0, 300, -1, 1);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        square.translate(4, 0);
    else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        square.translate(-4, 0);
    else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        square.translate(0, 4);
    else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        square.translate(0, -4);

    //also add code to toggle rotation/scaling
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R)
    {
        rotating = !rotating;
    }

    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        scaling = !scaling;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   
}
```

Comment: Your "square" class better represents an arbitrary quad, and your area calculation is incorrect even if it were a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale an object, you simply have to multiply each vertex by your scaling factor. A scaling factor of 1.0 will do nothing while a scaling factor of 2.0 will double de position of each vertex, hence scaling it AND probably translating it.

If you want the object to stay in place, you'll have to first translate it to your object's center, scale, then translate back to it's original position.

That is if you want to do the job software.

You should consider using Matrix functions. glRotatef, glTranslatef and glScalef.

Comment: Okay this sounds about right but then when I get it to double in size and then I want it to get smaller and then bigger so do I then divide it by 2.0?

Comment: When you want to get it smaller, you still multiplies, but with fractions like 0.5 ( halves the size ), 0.25 ( one quarter of the size ), 0.1 ( 10% of it's original size ) and so on.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an idea of how to code it? Like with my code would I need to write something
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   oldX = vertices[i][0];
  vertices[i][0] = vertices[i][0] * 2.0 etc...
  }

Comment: yeah, replacing 2.0 with sx for vertices[i][0]; and using sy for vertices[i][1]; You already figured out how to do rotations, this is way more basic you should have no problem implementing it.